# Why does nickname in all caps look bad?

Tags: capitalization

Someone commented my post like this,

> Anyways, all capital nicks look very bad.

He suddenly mentioned this. Is there any general reason that nickname in all caps look bad?

Comment: In text, all-caps has come to be understood as 'shouting'. However, it shouldn't be too objectionable in small amounts such as your user name.

Comment: ALL CAPS IS HARD TO PARSE IN GENERAL. IT IS EASIER TO SCAN TEXT WHICH HAS STRUCTURE AND INTERNAL DIFFERENTIATION. IN ADDITION, ON THE INTERNET, ALL CAPS IS THE EQUIVALENT OF SHOUTING, AND THEREFORE IS CONSIDERED RUDE, AS SHOUTING IS CONSIDERED RUDE IN PUBLIC. SIMILARLY, A USERNAME IN ALL CAPS MAKES IT APPEAR THAT THE USER IS EITHER EGOTISTICAL AND TRYING TO DRAW UNWARRANTED ATTENTION TO HIMSELF, OR THAT HE'S A GERIATRIC UNFAMILIAR WITH THE NORMS AND ETIQUETTE OF THE INTERNET. DON'T USE ALL-CAPS NICKS.

Comment: Sometimes a word is written all in capitals because it is very important. Most nicks, other than abbreviations, do not use all capitals so it is possible that some people may feel you think you are more important than other people.  If you wish to avoid the risk of people thinking that then, yes, changing your nick might be a good idea..  .

Comment: @DanBron it's only a nickname, not the entire Britannica, so yes avoid using CAPS in texts and messages but for such a short nickname as the OP's it aint so bad a crime :) But as the OP may have noticed, some people have lower threshold of tolerance than others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I take it the all-caps put you off reading the entire comment (which was, at least partially, the point): so let me render the bit relevant to usernames in more conventional orthography: *similarly, a username in all caps makes it appear that the user is either **egotistical and trying to draw unwarranted attention to himself**, or that he's a geriatric unfamiliar with the norms and etiquette or the Internet. Don't use all caps*. He's an example of people bridling at an all-caps name in the wild, and a comic on the same topic.

Comment: @DanBron the question is primarily opinion based, and I'll explain why. Some users might infer a nickname in CAPS is someone on a ego trip (etc.)  but not everyone. I dislike CAPS in general, but in small doses I can tolerate them. Other people more, other people much less. Generally speaking, CAPS should be used in moderation. The comment  in CAPS left by you was not brief in the slightest, and overstated its message. As an afterthought, do you find the term CAPS, written in capital letters, objectionable in itself?

Comment: @Mari-LouA BTW what does OP stand for? Original Poster, Lawrence?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I understand there is more than one issue with caps, some which apply to long texts, some which apply to usernames (which issues I was trying to highlight in my second comment), and some which fly in the face of standard orthography (which is the wire your example of "CAPS" trips over, and yes, why is bugs me: *caps* is a common noun, *CAPS* implies an acronym or proper noun, so the semantics are different). There's a whole Wikipedia article on how [capitalization can change the meaning of English words](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym).

Comment: Yes, OP stands for Original Poster or Post. @DanBron Yes, caps is also   plural for *cap*, two or more (baseball) caps to be precise. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, like almost all words, *cap* has more than one meaning, one of which is a kind of hat, and another is a letter case. By contrast, *CAPS* has no universally standard meaning at all (though I'm sure it's been used as an acronym in many many different contexts).

Comment: @TingChoe Yes, I normally use OP to refer to the Original Poster (the person), but I've seen it used to refer to the Original Post (the text) itself as well.

Comment: But when someone complains about block capital letters being used in a text, they write CAPS and everyone immediately  understands. No risk of ambiguity, CAPS is shorter, and quicker  than writing "block  capital letters" or *uppercase*, or majuscule.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They'd be equally well understood if they simply wrote *caps*. They write *CAPS* to emphasize through illustration, a kind of textual hand gesture, as I did above on my annoying all caps comment. But hey, maybe you like CAPS because Italians love hand gestures ;)

Comment: @DanBron At the risk of adding fuel where I'm trying to pour oil (please excuse the horribly mixed metaphor :P), I'd like to note that Mari-LouA's CAPS and your NICKS are of a similar nature in the context of your critique. We're also digressing from the tenor of OP's question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (see above)

Comment: Congratulations on your new nick

Comment: @Lawrence It's ok, I'm wearing my asbestos underpants. But I'm not clear on the similarity you're drawing between "caps" and "nicks". If you mean my capitalization of NICKS is nonstandard, yes, that was the point of my obnoxious first comment. If you mean *nicks*, so spelled, for username, is nonstandard, two points: (1) it's been used in online communities since at least the IRC says, and so has somewhat of an established pedigree (certainly relative to the all-caps *CAPS*), and (2) yet I still don't like it, and try to avoid it (note the more frequent use of "username" in my 1st comment)...

Comment: @Lawrence .. I used it to tie it back to OP's use to make my meaning clear, and to save on some characters (brevity is not my strong suit). If you meant something else by your analogy, can you try rephrasing?

Comment: @davidlol Yes, I changed. Even though there is only one person who are offended by my nickname because of the reason you mentioned, it's better to change because it's free.

Comment: @TingChoe I tried to find an example in another community I'm in where I saw a row created by a guy who annoyed several people (not me!) with his all caps name, but I lost the link :/ I'm sorry. And yes, congrats on the new nick.

Comment: @DanBron Point taken regarding *all*-caps (though my keyboard has a key called "Caps Lock", which tends to lend some legitimacy to the use of the word *Caps*). Nevertheless, both *caps* and *nicks*, however capitalised, *aren't* ambiguous in the respective contexts above.

Comment: @Lawrence My keyboard also has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, just tell you that space is at a premium on keycaps and that keyboard designers consider standalone words to be sentence initial, so it doesn't really have bearing or provide any information on how these words would be abbreviated or not or capitalized or not in other places. And yes, context is an extremely powerful tool and can make almost any string of letters have almost any meaning, but the whole point of discussing a word's legitimacy is whether is has meaning *without* context, as in a dictionary!

Comment: It's purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: An all-caps nickname looks like an acronym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the discussion of the above comments;

There is a netiquette;

> Don't use nickname in all caps.

Some people agree with the rule because

- A username in all caps makes it appear that the user is egotistical and trying to draw unwarranted attention to himself.
- A username in all caps makes it appear that he's a geriatric unfamiliar with the norms and etiquette of the Internet.
- Most nicks do not use all capitals so it is possible that some people may feel you think you are more important than other people.

Some people disagree with the rule because

- It shouldn't be too objectionable in small amounts such as user names.